# Python equivalent of rpm -Va

Tags: python, centos, rpm

I need to query the rpm db to verify all packages. I can do this with `rpm -Va` from a command line but I have a python binary that is collecting some other information. I was wondering if there was a python equivalent.

I know I can use `subprocess.Popen(["rpm","Va"])` but the command line query takes very long so I was hoping there was a more fully python way of doing it. I've looked at the rpm python module but I can't quite see how to do what I want to do from the documentation.

TIA

Edit: rephrased some stuff

Comment: "I can't quite follow the documentation" - do you want us to read the documentation for you?

Comment: ....Well, maybe. What I mean to say is that I don't understand how to do what I want to do from reading the documentation. If you know of somewhere in the documentation that says "The equivalent of rpm -Va is xyz," I may have missed it and would appreciate reiteration...or at least a link.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the C implementation (built into the `rpm` command) is slower than... well... any other? If your Python uses `librpm`, it's still calling into C. And if you had something that was doing checksumming of a large number of files in native Python... well, a reasonable person would expect it to be *slower* unless you broke it into threads, and if that's what you wanted to do, you could do the same with the command-line invocation (with N processes each handling 1/Nth of the total list of packages).

Comment: ...something like `rpm -Qa | xargs -d $'\n' -P 4 rpm -V` if you have 4 CPUs, f/e. (Not tested; I don't have any RPM-based distro handy).

Comment: ...but point being, if your real goal is to come up with a faster alternative to `rpm -Va`, you should probably asking how to do *that* (maybe on [unix.se] rather than here), rather than assuming that the Python rpm module is somehow going to be better-performing than the canonical entrypoint to the primary C implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The rpm-Python bindings do not provide direct bindings to the routines that perform rpm -VA.

There are two approaches to implementing rpm -Va in Python:

1) call the routines in rpmlib directly from Python. This approach assumes that you can set up the data structures that need to be passed correctly, but is exactly what rpm itself does.

2) use the existing rpmdb header retrieval mechanism and tag retrieval mechanisms to get the information that is needed to perform a verify and do that in Python. See lib/verify.c for what information contained in headers is verified.

There may be Python code in either yum or dnf that does a verify through method #2